# MySQL Conditional Column Response

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to have a conditional MySQL response based on if `users.address_privacy is = 1`.

If `users.address_privacy = 1` then I want to only return `user_address.city` and `user_address.state`.

If `users.address_privacy = 0` then I want to return `user_address.*`

This is the basic setup of the query I want to apply the if/else functionality to.

```
SELECT items.*, user_address.*, users.address_privacy
FROM items
INNER JOIN users ON (users.user_id = items.user_id)
INNER JOIN user_address ON (user_address.user_id = items.user_id)
```

Is this possible or would I have to process it after the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never gave us the other columns in the `user_address` table besides `city` and `state`, so I assumed in my answer that there are two more fields called `column1` and `column2`.  You can use a `CASE` statement to conditionally show or hide certain columns based on the privacy setting.  Additional `CASE` statements can be added to cover all the coumns from the `user_address` table.

```
SELECT items.*,
    CASE WHEN users.address_privacy = 0 THEN user_address.column1 ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN users.address_privacy = 0 THEN user_address.column2 ELSE '' END,
    users_address.city,
    users_address.state,
    users.address_privacy
FROM items
INNER JOIN users ON (users.user_id = items.user_id)
INNER JOIN user_address ON (user_address.user_id = items.user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim that worked perfectly! The other columns were address1 and address2. I plugged those in and I'm good to go. Thanks again.